# Слайдер с вертикальными линиями (плавность, структура, совет)

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, slider, анимация

В js, jqury не силен, ради интереса захотелось сделать что то [подобное](http://framesoflife.armani.com/en-us/the-campaign/stories/) начал с простой смены слайдов, проблема в том что когда водишь мышью туда сюда слайдер сума сходит) как от этого избавиться ?

P.S. *Такое ощущение что анимация не замкнута, не отдельная функция, а делает часть того и чать другого и в результате каша. В общем любому совету буду рад. вот [код](http://codepen.io/junior-web-dev/pen/XNeELR) на codepen.*

```
<p data-height="511" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="XNeELR" data-default-tab="result" data-user="junior-web-dev" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="XNeELR" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/junior-web-dev/pen/XNeELR/">XNeELR</a> by junior-web-dev (<a href="http://codepen.io/junior-web-dev">@junior-web-dev</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: решение зависит от ожидаемого поведения. в данный момент при наведении на каждую часть слайда запускается смена анимации. потому при быстром наведении на все поочередно анимация дергается, т.к. пытается потоком запустить каждый слайд. как вариант, можно поставить задержку на смену слайда, например

Comment: $(".screen-line").hover(function(e){
   
   clearTimeout(timerStartAnim);
    var timerStartAnim = setTimeout(function(){
              elem = e.currentTarget;
              animStart(elem);
              },400)
    }); 
 На ховере есть задержка перед запуском функции animStart. Я ее увеличил до 1000 теперь если поводить мишкой дольше 1000 начинает все мигать) но все как и было, возможно задержка не правильно реализована?

Comment: изменяя тот интервал, по идее, изменяется задержка перед сменой слайдов. то бишь, проходит секунда, а потом каждое изображение точно так же пытается добавиться. а надо задержку перед выполнением всей функции смены. **P.S.** по сути, если надо повторить функционал, то можно его изучить на оригинальном сайте через просмотр кода страницы

Comment: lexxl благодарю за помощь, ошибка была в том что clearTimeout не очищал таймер он не видел переменную с id таймера, так как таймер был объявлен не глобально а в функции, и еще исправил баг с ховером hoverOut запускал все повторно, я очистил чтобы этого не происходило, сейчас все хорошо. Вопрос пока не закрываю, может будут еще вопросы по поводу этого слайдера. Спасибо.